# nom & borrowed value does not live long enough error

Tags: rust, parser-combinators, nom

Trying to work with [nom](https://lib.rs/crates/nom) and iterate over my result, but I can't figure out why this borrowed value doesn't live long enough. Still new to Rust and have been head-banging for hours. Would appreciate help!

```rs
use anyhow;
use nom::{
    bytes::complete::{tag, take},
    character::complete::newline,
    combinator::rest,
    multi::separated_list1,
    sequence::separated_pair,
    IResult,
};

pub fn parse(raw: String) -> anyhow::Result<()> {
    let (_, lines) = parse_multiline(&raw)?;

    for line in lines.iter() {
        let (label, value) = line;

        println!("label: {}, value: {}", label, value);
    }

    Ok(())
}

fn parse_multiline(i: &str) -> IResult<&str, Vec<(&str, &str)>> {
    separated_list1(
        newline,
        separated_pair(
            take(14usize),
            tag(" : "),
            rest,
        ),
    )(i)
}
```

And the error:

```
error[E0597]: `raw` does not live long enough
  --> src/parser/person.rs:12:38
   |
12 |     let (_, lines) = parse_multiline(&raw)?;
   |                      ----------------^^^^-
   |                      |               |
   |                      |               borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                      argument requires that `raw` is borrowed for `'static`
...
21 | }
   | - `raw` dropped here while still borrowed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `parse_multiline()` you return [`IResult<&str, Vec<(&str, &str)>>`](https://docs.rs/nom/6.1.0/nom/type.IResult.html). This means that if your `parse_multiline()` fails, then it returns [`nom::Err`](https://docs.rs/nom/6.1.0/nom/enum.Err.html)`<`[`nom::error::Error`](https://docs.rs/nom/6.1.0/nom/error/struct.Error.html)`<&str>>` which has a reference to `i`/`&raw`.

Thus in `parse()`, `parse_multiline(raw)?` propagates that error further, which would return a reference to `raw`, which would not live long enough.

---

If you want to retain `fn parse(raw: String)`, then the you can use [`Result::map_err()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.map_err) and then [`nom::Err::map()`](https://docs.rs/nom/6.1.0/nom/enum.Err.html#method.map), to convert the `&str` into an owned `String` on error.

```
// nom = "6.1"
use nom::error::Error;

pub fn parse(raw: String) -> anyhow::Result<()> {
    let (_, lines) = parse_multiline(&raw)
        .map_err(|err| err.map(|err| Error::new(err.input.to_string(), err.code)))?;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Ahhh! I never thought about the error having references--I was overly fixated on the successful result. Thanks!

Comment: @neezer To be fair, only given the compile error, then it can be kinda confusing indeed :)

Answer (score 1):

@vallentin's answer is great. And for nom v7, there is a shorter version of it

```rust
// nom = "7"
use nom::error::Error;

pub fn parse(raw: String) -> anyhow::Result<()> {
    let (_, lines) = parse_multiline(&raw)
        .map_err(|err| err.to_owned())?;

    // ...
}
```